# Feedback on simple Merge algorithm

Tags: haskell

I am writing a simple merge algorithm in Haskell. I wanted to add simple logging, hence am using the Writer Monad to include logging.

```
type ArrayWithLogging a = WriterT [String] Identity [a]

merge :: (Show a, Ord a) => ArrayWithLogging a -> ArrayWithLogging a -> ArrayWithLogging a
merge al bl = do
    a <- al
    b <- bl
    case (a, b) of
        ([], b') -> tell ["Returning " ++ show b'] >> return b'
        (a', []) -> tell ["Returning " ++ show a'] >> return a'
        (a'@(x:xs), b'@(y:ys)) -> if (x <= y)
                                    then tell ["Min " ++ show x ++ " merging " ++ show xs ++ " with " ++ show b] 
                                        >> ((merge (return xs) (return b')) >>= \z -> return (x : z))
                                  else tell ["Min " ++ show y ++ " merging " ++ show a ++ " with " ++ show ys] 
                                        >> ((merge (return a') (return ys)) >>= \z -> return (y : z))
```

I feel there are too many returns inside the monadic context. Is this style correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start simple. First of all, your code seems fine. However, as you've noticed yourself, there's an abundance of `returns`. Several of them don't seem necessary, so let us inspect some patterns:

```hs
((merge (return a') (return ys)) >>= \z -> return (y : z))
```

The pattern `x >>= \z -> return (f z)` is the same as `fmap f x`. That already reduces the number of returns by two:

```hs
type ArrayWithLogging a = WriterT [String] Identity [a]

merge :: (Show a, Ord a) => ArrayWithLogging a -> ArrayWithLogging a -> ArrayWithLogging a
merge al bl = do
    a <- al
    b <- bl
    case (a, b) of
        ([], b') -> tell ["Returning " ++ show b'] >> return b'
        (a', []) -> tell ["Returning " ++ show a'] >> return a'
        (a'@(x:xs), b'@(y:ys)) -> if (x <= y)
                                    then tell ["Min " ++ show x ++ " merging " ++ show xs ++ " with " ++ show b] 
                                        >> fmap (x:) (merge (return xs) (return b'))
                                    else tell ["Min " ++ show y ++ " merging " ++ show a ++ " with " ++ show ys] 
                                        >> fmap (y:) (merge (return a') (return ys))
```

Now, for the next step, let's get rid of the `WriterT` monad in the first two arguments. There's no reason for that, and it further removes the `return`:

```hs
merge :: (Show a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> ArrayWithLogging a
merge a b = do
    case (a, b) of
        ([], b') -> tell ["Returning " ++ show b'] >> return b'
        (a', []) -> tell ["Returning " ++ show a'] >> return a'
        (a'@(x:xs), b'@(y:ys)) -> if (x <= y)
                                    then tell ["Min " ++ show x ++ " merging " ++ show xs ++ " with " ++ show b] 
                                        >> fmap (x:) (merge xs b')
                                    else tell ["Min " ++ show y ++ " merging " ++ show a ++ " with " ++ show ys] 
                                        >> fmap (y:) (merge a' ys)
```

We can still get the old variant by using the following `merge'`:

```hs
merge' a1 b1 =
  a <- a1
  b <- b1
  merge a b
```

Now that we've reduced function pretty far (but didn't lose any functionality!), we can go ahead and change some indentation to make our intend more clear. Furthermore, let us also introduce a small helper called `message`:

```hs
merge :: (Show a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> ArrayWithLogging a
merge a b = do
    case (a, b) of
        ([], b') -> tell ["Returning " ++ show b'] >> return b'
        (a', []) -> tell ["Returning " ++ show a'] >> return a'
        (a'@(x:xs), b'@(y:ys)) -> 
            if (x <= y)
                then message x xs b  >> fmap (x:) (merge xs b')
                else message y a  ys >> fmap (y:) (merge a' ys)
  where
   message e ls rs = tell ["Min " ++ show e ++ " merging " ++ show ls ++ " with " ++ show rs]
```

OK, let's reiterate our steps:

1. We changed `x >>= \z -> (f z)` to `fmap f x`
2. We changed the arguments into their non-monad variant
3. We introduced another function to keep the old behaviour (if necessary)
4. We changed the indentation to make sure that it looks nicer.
5. We introduced a small helper to make sure that we don't repeat ourselves.

And those are all the non-opinionated (well, except the last one) changes I'd recommend to you. In my personal opinion, the function gets even a little bit nicer if we use pattern matching on the arguments:

```hs
type ArrayWithLogging a = WriterT [String] Identity [a]

merge :: (Show a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> ArrayWithLogging a
merge a        []     = tell ["Returning " ++ show a] >> return a
merge []       b      = tell ["Returning " ++ show b] >> return b
merge a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys)
  | x <= y    = message x xs b  >> fmap (x:) (merge xs b)
  | otherwise = message y a  ys >> fmap (y:) (merge a ys)
  where
    message e ls rs = tell ["Min " ++ show e ++ " merging " ++ show ls ++ " with " ++ show rs]

merge' :: (Show a, Ord a) => ArrayWithLogging a-> ArrayWithLogging a-> ArrayWithLogging a
merge' a b = do
   a1 <- a
   b1 <- b
   merge a1 b1
```

Comment: Beautiful! I had a follow up question. I am reading "Haskell Programming From First Principles", and the author says not to use Writer because its either too lazy or too strict for the problem you are solving, uses a lot of memory and we cannot retrieve the logged values till computation is complete. Is there a better alternative to Writer for logging?

Comment: @RohitG Sorry, I've been away from the Haskell ecosystem for too long to give an adequate answer for a `Writer` alternative :(